# подключение ts файла в html

Tags: html, typescript

как подключить ts файл в html.Как подключить js файл я знаю но ts нет.

Comment: Потому что никак?

Comment: Компилируйте в js и подключайте

Answer (score 1):

насколько я понимаю, браузеры еще не умеют выполнять ts, они выполняют js. Поэтому ts нужно скомпилить в js и подключить уже js.

Comment: я использую WS у меня автоматически  переводится ts в js, но когда   путь прописываю  к js файлу то он не работает

Comment: хотя работает но оно выделяет красным var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.strokeStyle = "red";
getContext - это часть кода с ts файла

Comment: выделяет только - getContext

Comment: а canvas-элемент с именем `myCanvas` на html-странице есть? он расположен выше скрипта?

Comment: myCanvas - елемент html

Comment: точнее это Id елемента

Comment: в js - файле всё норм, в тайп - скриптовом только подчёркивает getContext

Comment: S2339:Property 'getContext' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' - ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
  var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('myCanvas');
```

Comment: <HTMLCanvasElement> вот этого не хватало